# Compress memory on low Ram VM

Tags: kernel-modules, compression, ram

Is there a way to get out more out of your limited Ram on a VM?

I have a VM running on a cloud hoster and try to optimize a quite low on RAM mashine.

I heard, there is a way to compress parts in the memory if all free memory is in use called [zram](https://wiki.debian.org/ZRam)

How do I get this running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained on the [Zram Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/ZRam):

> zram (previously called compcache) can create RAM based block devices. It is an experimental (staging) module of the Linux kernel since 3.2.

So If you are using a kernel before 3.2 you need to copy the following script (taken from [here](https://wiki.debian.org/ZRam)) to `/etc/init.d/zram`:

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          zram
# Required-Start:    $local_fs
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs
# Default-Start:     S
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Use compressed RAM as in-memory swap
# Description:       Use compressed RAM as in-memory swap
### END INIT INFO

# Author: Antonio Galea <antonio.galea@gmail.com>
# Thanks to Przemysław Tomczyk for suggesting swapoff parallelization

FRACTION=75

MEMORY=`perl -ne'/^MemTotal:\s+(\d+)/ && print $1*1024;' < /proc/meminfo`
CPUS=`grep -c processor /proc/cpuinfo`
SIZE=$(( MEMORY * FRACTION / 100 / CPUS ))

case "$1" in
  "start")
    param=`modinfo zram|grep num_devices|cut -f2 -d:|tr -d ' '`
    modprobe zram $param=$CPUS
    for n in `seq $CPUS`; do
      i=$((n - 1))
      echo $SIZE > /sys/block/zram$i/disksize
      mkswap /dev/zram$i
      swapon /dev/zram$i -p 10
    done
    ;;
  "stop")
    for n in `seq $CPUS`; do
      i=$((n - 1))
      swapoff /dev/zram$i && echo "disabled disk $n of $CPUS" &
    done
    wait
    sleep .5
    modprobe -r zram
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: `basename $0` (start | stop)"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

give it executable rights with

```
chmod +x /etc/init.d/zram
```

then instruct you system to start it at boot time, with the command

```
insserv zram
```

After the next reboot you will see the swap with

```
swapon -s
```

which will look like:

```
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/zram0                              partition   381668  380716  10
```